# Extract straddling byte array content to std::bitset

Tags: c++

I need to extract content from a byte array (std::vector) to bitsets. The content could be straddling two bytes.

Here is my unit test:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> val = { 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF }; // is 101010111100110111101111

std::bitset<4> a = extractToBitSet<4>( val, 0 ); // should be 0x0A: 1010
std::bitset<8> bc = extractToBitSet<8>( val, 4 ); // should be 0xBC: 10111100
std::bitset<12> def = extractToBitSet<12>( val, 12 ); // should be 0x0DEF: 110111101111

CPPUNIT_ASSERT( a.to_string() == "1010" );
CPPUNIT_ASSERT( bc.to_string() == "10111100" );
CPPUNIT_ASSERT( def.to_string() == "110111101111" );

unsigned long aVal = a.to_ulong();
unsigned long bcVal = bc.to_ulong();
unsigned long defVal = def.to_ulong();

CPPUNIT_ASSERT( aVal == 0x0A );
CPPUNIT_ASSERT( bcVal == 0xBC );
CPPUNIT_ASSERT( defVal == 0x0DEF );
```

I came up with this solution:

```
template<size_t _Count> void reverseBitSet( std::bitset<_Count>& bitset )
{
    bool val;
    for ( size_t pos = 0; pos < _Count/2; ++pos )
    {
        val = bitset[pos];
        bitset[pos] = bitset[_Count-pos-1];
        bitset[_Count-pos-1] = val;
    }
}

template<size_t _Count> std::bitset<_Count> extractToBitSet( const std::vector<uint8_t>& data, size_t offset )
{
    std::bitset<_Count> res;

    size_t pos = 0;
    uint8_t tempVal;
    std::bitset<8> tempBitSet;

    while ( pos < _Count )
    {
        tempVal = data[ (offset + pos)/8 ];

        tempBitSet = tempVal;
        reverseBitSet( tempBitSet );
        res[pos] = tempBitSet[(offset + pos)%8];

        ++pos;
    }

    reverseBitSet( res );

    return res;
}
```

It works (my test pass) but it seems very unefficient with all those temporary bitsets being created + many reverse operations.

Is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: If it's any consolation, an optimizing compiler will ellide those temporary bitsets, so you aren't performing as many copies.

Comment: Surely....but Debug builds are going to be really slow....and reverse operations won't be taken off...

Answer (score 6):

Why all the reversing? You could just explicitly set each bit as you go based on the specific operation you're performing. Just the one loop:

```
template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> extract(std::vector<uint8_t> const& vs, size_t offset) {
    std::bitset<N> res;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        size_t full_off = offset + i;
        auto& byte = vs[full_off / 8];
        auto bit = byte & (1 << (7 - (full_off % 8)));

        res.set(N-i-1, bit);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @RichardHodges: Agree, but at least this is much better than what I had originally!

Comment: @RichardHodges bitset only allows to set one bit at a time.

Comment: @Leon sure, but it supports bitwise shift, AND, OR and assignment from integer types so it can be treated as a shift register.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, but straightforward manipulation of the bitset as a shift register will result in O(N^2) time complexity. I feel that a O(N) divide-and-conquer algorithm is possible, but it will hardly deserve being called nicer than this simple bit-by-bit version.

Comment: @Leon why o(n^2) if we shift in 8 bits at a time where possible?

Comment: @RichardHodges Because shifting a bitset (no matter by what amount)  is an O(N) operation, and you will have to perform it O(N) times. bitset is not a hardware shift register with constant time shifts.

Comment: @Leon i'm going to benchmark that. I strongly suspect that bitset<(N <= 128)> all happens in a register.

Comment: @RichardHodges I won't dispute that. When using O(N) notation I had large Ns in mind.

Comment: @Leon alternative answer posted. I'd be interested to know if it performs better/worse than the bitwise version.

Comment: @RichardHodges Did you time it?

Comment: @Barry test results for 12 bits with an offset of 12 posted. The bytewise version is 3x faster for this configuration.

Comment: @Leon see above. These tests were run on a 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a bytewise version. The difference here is that for inner chunks of 8-bits, data is moved into the accumulator bytes-at-a-time, while the ends are treated as partial-byte shift/mask operations.

I strongly suspect that this will be more efficient:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>


template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> extract(std::vector<uint8_t> const& vs, size_t offset)
{
    std::bitset<N> accumulator;

    auto lead_byte = [&accumulator] (auto byte, auto offset, auto bits)
    {
        static constexpr std::uint8_t masks[] = {
            0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff
        };
        auto word_length = 8 - bits;

        byte >>= (word_length - offset);
        byte &= masks[bits-1];
        accumulator = byte;
    };

    auto tail_byte = [&accumulator](std::uint8_t byte, std::size_t bits)
    {
        static constexpr std::uint8_t masks[] = {
            0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff
        };
        accumulator <<= bits;
        byte >>= (8-bits);
        byte &= masks[bits-1];
        accumulator |= byte;
    };

    auto middle_byte = [&accumulator](std::uint8_t byte)
    {
        accumulator <<= 8;
        accumulator |= byte;
    };

    std::size_t bits_to_go = N;
    const std::uint8_t* p = vs.data() + (offset / 8);
    offset %= 8;

    for ( ; bits_to_go ; ++p)
    {
        if (offset != 0)
        {
            auto chunk = std::min(bits_to_go, 8-offset);
            lead_byte(*p, offset, chunk);
            bits_to_go -= chunk;
            offset = 0;
        }
        else if (bits_to_go < 8)
        {
            tail_byte(*p, bits_to_go);
            bits_to_go = 0;
        }
        else {
            middle_byte(*p);
            bits_to_go -= 8;
        }
    }

    return accumulator;
}






int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> val = { 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF }; // is 101010111100110111101111

    std::bitset<4> a = extract<4>( val, 0 ); // should be 0x0A: 1010
    std::bitset<8> bc = extract<8>( val, 4 ); // should be 0xBC: 10111100
    std::bitset<12> def = extract<12>( val, 12 ); // should be 0x0DEF: 110111101111

    assert( a.to_string() == "1010" );
    assert( bc.to_string() == "10111100" );
    assert( def.to_string() == "110111101111" );

    unsigned long aVal = a.to_ulong();
    unsigned long bcVal = bc.to_ulong();
    unsigned long defVal = def.to_ulong();

    assert( aVal == 0x0A );
    assert( bcVal == 0xBC );
    assert( defVal == 0x0DEF );

    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << bc << std::endl;
    std::cout << def << std::endl;
}
```

Here is a test harness - the moment of truth...

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>


template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> extract_bitwise(std::vector<uint8_t> const& vs, size_t offset) {
    std::bitset<N> res;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        size_t full_off = offset + i;
        auto& byte = vs[full_off / 8];
        auto bit = byte & (1 << (7 - (full_off % 8)));

        res.set(N-i-1, bit);
    }
    return res;
}

template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> extract(std::vector<uint8_t> const& vs, size_t offset)
{
    std::bitset<N> accumulator;

    auto lead_byte = [&accumulator] (auto byte, auto offset, auto bits)
    {
        static constexpr std::uint8_t masks[] = {
            0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff
        };
        auto word_length = 8 - bits;

        byte >>= (word_length - offset);
        byte &= masks[bits-1];
        accumulator = byte;
    };

    auto tail_byte = [&accumulator](std::uint8_t byte, std::size_t bits)
    {
        static constexpr std::uint8_t masks[] = {
            0x01, 0x03, 0x07, 0x0f, 0x1f, 0x3f, 0x7f, 0xff
        };
        accumulator <<= bits;
        byte >>= (8-bits);
        byte &= masks[bits-1];
        accumulator |= byte;
    };

    auto middle_byte = [&accumulator](std::uint8_t byte)
    {
        accumulator <<= 8;
        accumulator |= byte;
    };

    std::size_t bits_to_go = N;
    const std::uint8_t* p = vs.data() + (offset / 8);
    offset %= 8;

    for ( ; bits_to_go ; ++p)
    {
        if (offset != 0)
        {
            auto chunk = std::min(bits_to_go, 8-offset);
            lead_byte(*p, offset, chunk);
            bits_to_go -= chunk;
            offset = 0;
        }
        else if (bits_to_go < 8)
        {
            tail_byte(*p, bits_to_go);
            bits_to_go = 0;
        }
        else {
            middle_byte(*p);
            bits_to_go -= 8;
        }
    }

    return accumulator;
}



auto time_it = [](auto&& func, auto&& ident)
{
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    func();
    auto then = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto diff = then - now;

    using fms = std::chrono::duration<double, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>;
    std::cout << ident << " : " << fms(std::chrono::duration_cast<fms>(diff)).count() << "ms\n";
};

static constexpr std::size_t test_size = 1000000;

using byte_array = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;
using byte_arrays = std::vector<byte_array>;
template<std::size_t N> using bitset_array = std::vector<std::bitset<N>>;

byte_arrays generate_test_data()
{
    byte_arrays result;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint8_t> dist(0, 255);

    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < test_size ; ++i)
    {
        byte_array ba(64);
        std::generate(ba.begin(), ba.end(), [&] { return dist(eng); });
        result.push_back(ba);
    }
    return result;
}

template<size_t _Count> void reverseBitSet( std::bitset<_Count>& bitset )
{
    bool val;
    for ( size_t pos = 0; pos < _Count/2; ++pos )
    {
        val = bitset[pos];
        bitset[pos] = bitset[_Count-pos-1];
        bitset[_Count-pos-1] = val;
    }
}

template<size_t _Count> std::bitset<_Count> extractToBitSet( const std::vector<uint8_t>& data, size_t offset )
{
    std::bitset<_Count> res;

    size_t pos = 0;
    uint8_t tempVal;
    std::bitset<8> tempBitSet;

    while ( pos < _Count )
    {
        tempVal = data[ (offset + pos)/8 ];

        tempBitSet = tempVal;
        reverseBitSet( tempBitSet );
        res[pos] = tempBitSet[(offset + pos)%8];

        ++pos;
    }

    reverseBitSet( res );

    return res;
}

template<std::size_t N>
void run_tests_for_bits(const byte_arrays& test_data)
{
    bitset_array<N> bytewise(test_size), bitwise(test_size), original(test_size);

    auto make_ident = [](auto&& preamble) {
        return std::string(std::move(preamble)) + ' ' + std::to_string(N) + " bits";
    };

    std::cout << make_ident("running tests for") << '\n';


    time_it([&]
            {
                std::transform(test_data.begin(),
                               test_data.end(),
                               bytewise.begin(),
                               [](auto& vec)
                               {
                                   return extract<N> (vec, 12);
                               });
            }, make_ident("bytewise"));

    time_it([&]
            {
                std::transform(test_data.begin(),
                               test_data.end(),
                               bitwise.begin(),
                               [](auto& vec)
                               {
                                   return extract_bitwise<N> (vec, 12);
                               });
            }, make_ident("bitwise"));

    time_it([&]
            {
                std::transform(test_data.begin(),
                               test_data.end(),
                               original.begin(),
                               [](auto& vec)
                               {
                                   return extractToBitSet<N> (vec, 12);
                               });
            }, make_ident("original"));

    std::cout << "checking results\n";

    auto mm1 = std::mismatch(bytewise.begin(), bytewise.end(), bitwise.begin());
    auto mm2 = std::mismatch(bytewise.begin(), bytewise.end(), original.begin());

    if (mm1.first != bytewise.end())
        std::cout << "mismatch between bytewise and bitwise at index " << std::distance(bytewise.begin(), mm1.first) << '\n';
    else if (mm2.first != bytewise.end())
        std::cout << "mismatch between bytewise and original at index " << std::distance(bytewise.begin(), mm1.first) << '\n';
    else
        std::cout << "all good\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "building test data\n";
    auto test_data = generate_test_data();
    run_tests_for_bits<12>(test_data);
    run_tests_for_bits<24>(test_data);
    run_tests_for_bits<52>(test_data);
}
```

Sample Results:

```
building test data
running tests for 12 bits
bytewise 12 bits : 117.462ms
bitwise 12 bits : 316.362ms
original 12 bits : 2836.99ms
checking results
all good
running tests for 24 bits
bytewise 24 bits : 274.765ms
bitwise 24 bits : 624.927ms
original 24 bits : 5619.05ms
checking results
all good
running tests for 52 bits
bytewise 52 bits : 519.265ms
bitwise 52 bits : 1260.75ms
original 52 bits : 11693.6ms
checking results
all good
```

With a little editing (test data array sizes) we can ramp up the test to a larger number of bits:

(I have removed the 'reverser' method here as it becomes extraordinarily long for long bit lengths.)

```
running tests for 256 bits
bytewise 256 bits : 3912.57ms
bitwise 256 bits : 6367.22ms

running tests for 512 bits
bytewise 512 bits : 10610.2ms
bitwise 512 bits : 12448.7ms
```

We can see that the timings for bitwise and bytewise methods eventually converge and cross just after 512 bits (on my machine).

```
running tests for 1024 bits
bytewise 1024 bits : 30070.6ms
bitwise 1024 bits : 25236.2ms
```

after which the bitwise method becomes more efficient.

```
running tests for 2048 bits
bytewise 2048 bits : 95648.4ms
bitwise 2048 bits : 47672.1ms
```

Comment: Will you please also add a benchmark for a large N (say 1024) just for completeness?

Comment: Yes. +1 for all the effort that you put into this answer.